# CakePHP3 'contain' doesn't retrieve data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using a query builder provided by CakePHP 3 to retrive "Offers" from database with records from others table using `['contain' => 'AnotherTable']` but only one of table put in `contain` array is retrieved, how can I make the two table records will be retrived?

**Query with two tables (only 'OfferBanners' has been retrived):**

```
$setting = [
            'fields' => ['id', 'product_id', 'date_start', 'date_end', 'name', 'description'],
            'contain' => ['Products', 'OfferBanners']
        ];
$offers = TableRegistry::get('Offers')
       ->find('all', $setting)->hydrate(false)->toArray();
```

**Result array:**

[Link to array pastebin](http://pastebin.com/82zqCtTW)

**Initialize from OffersTable:**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('offers');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    $this->belongsTo('Products', [
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('OfferBanners', [
        'foreignKey' => 'offer_id'
    ]);
}
```

**Initialize from ProductsTable:**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->table('products');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    $this->belongsTo('Stores', [
        'foreignKey' => 'store_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Bookings', [
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('ProductFeatures', [
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Offers', [
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id'
    ]);
}
```

SQL from tables:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  product_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  store_id INT NOT NULL,
  sub_category_id INT NOT NULL,
  price DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME,
  modified DATETIME,
  FOREIGN KEY store_key (store_id) REFERENCES stores(id),
  FOREIGN KEY sub_category_key (sub_category_id) REFERENCES sub_categories(id)
);

CREATE TABLE offers (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  product_id  INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
  date_start DATETIME NOT NULL,
  date_end DATETIME NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME,
  modified DATETIME,
  FOREIGN KEY product_key (product_id) REFERENCES products(id)
);

CREATE TABLE offer_banners (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  path VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  offer_id INT NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME,
  modified DATETIME,
  FOREIGN KEY offer_key (offer_id) REFERENCES offers(id)
);
```

Comment: you did not select any field from the associated models

Comment: @arilia But in "OfferBanners" is retrived all fields

Comment: @arilia nothing is write in error.log

Comment: in your pastebin I don't see any field coming from OfferBanners

Comment: @arilia sorry I put the wrong array, I put the correct now: http://pastebin.com/82zqCtTW

Comment: still try to select at least one field from Products.

Comment: @arilia How I can make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$offers = TableRegistry::get('Offers');

$offers = $offers->find()
    ->select(['id', 'product_id', 'date_start', 'date_end', 'name', 'description'])
    ->select($offers->Products)
    ->select($offers->OfferBanners)
    ->contain(['Products', 'OfferBanners'])->hydrate(false)->toArray();
```

**edit:** Or, if you are using cake < 3.1

```
$offers = TableRegistry::get('Offers');

$offers = $offers->find()
    ->select(['id', 'product_id', 'date_start', 'date_end', 'name', 'description'])
    ->select(['Products.id']) // list your Products field list here
    ->select(['OfferBanners.id']) // list your OfferBanners field list here
    ->contain(['Products', 'OfferBanners'])->hydrate(false)->toArray();
```

or

```
$offers = $offers->find()
    ->select(['id', 'product_id', 'date_start', 'date_end', 'name', 'description'])
    ->contain([
        'Products' => function($q) {
            return $q->autoFields(true);
        },
        'OfferBanners' => function($q) {
            return $q->autoFields(true);
        }
    ])->hydrate(false)->toArray();
```

if you want to select specific fields use i.e.

```
   'OfferBanners' => function($q) {
            return $q->select([/* insert field list here */]);
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't work, prompt this error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\QueryCompiler.php on line 175

Comment: probably you are using cake < 3.1. If so I'll edit my question

Comment: I'm using cakephp 3.0

Comment: Thank you very much, I use the last exemple and works fine, one little more information: how can I select wich fields are retrived in 'OfferBanners' and 'Products' ?